# How to create stacked chart using ggplot from two data frames

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I would like to create a stacked chart using the ggplot2 library in R to create shaded areas (for Bananas and Kiwi). The problem is that data (Bananas, Kiwi) comes from two separate functions, thus there are two data objects.

```
plot(t, Bananas, type="l", xlab = "",xlim=c(0,70), ylim=c(0,1) lty=1)
lines(t, Kiwi, lty=2)
```

How can I implement two "data" objects in the ggplot?

```
p <- ggplot(data= , aes(x= t, group=, fill=)) + geom_density(adjust=1.5, position="fill") +
    theme_ipsum()
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal dataset that reproduces the problem?

Comment: That said, you can set different aesthetics on two different `geom_line` commands if you want.

Comment: Often it's best to `merge()` the two datasets before plotting.

Answer (score 0):

A good idea is to *join* the two data sets:

```
library(tidyverse)

#first create the data 
df_bananas <- data.frame(t=c(1:4),Bananas=c(2,4,8,10))
df_kiwis <- data.frame(t=c(2:4),Kiwis=c(3,6,9))

# then join the two data frames. Note that the fruit data are in "value" 
df_fruits <- full_join(df_bananas,df_kiwis)
head(df_fruits)

#ggplot2 likes "long" data frames i.e. the plotted data should be all in one column:
df_fruits_l <- pivot_longer(df_fruits, names_to = "fruits", cols =c(Bananas, Kiwis))
head(df_fruits_l) 

ggplot(data=df_fruits_l , aes(x= t, y=value, colour = fruits, fill= fruits))+
  geom_area(position = 'stack')+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

For more on join, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right?rq=1)